# C/C++ - How to make a singleton connection module in Apache HTTP Server?

Tags: c++, apache, singleton, apache2

Let's say I have this code for my `apache` module:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

#include <httpd.h>
#include <http_core.h>
#include <http_protocol.h>
#include <http_request.h>

#include <apr_strings.h>

int count = 0;

static void my_child_init(apr_pool_t *p, server_rec *s)
{
    count = 1000; //starts up with this number!
}

static int my_handler(request_rec *r)
{
    count++; //Increments here
    ap_rputs(std::to_string(count).c_str(), r);

    return OK;
}

static void register_hooks(apr_pool_t *pool)
{
    ap_hook_child_init(my_child_init, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_MIDDLE);
    ap_hook_handler(my_handler, NULL, NULL, APR_HOOK_LAST);
}

module AP_MODULE_DECLARE_DATA   myserver_module =
{
    STANDARD20_MODULE_STUFF,
    NULL,            // Per-directory configuration handler
    NULL,            // Merge handler for per-directory configurations
    NULL,            // Per-server configuration handler
    NULL,            // Merge handler for per-server configurations
    NULL,            // Any directives we may have for httpd
    register_hooks   // Our hook registering function
};
```

Now if I open my browser and go to `localhost/my_server` I see my `count` incrementing every time I refresh my page, creating a new HTTP request to `Apache`.

```
1001 //from connection 1
1002 //from connection 1
1003 //from connection 1
1004 //from connection 1
...
```

I was expecting that everytime I refresh, I see the `count` incrementing. But sometimes I see that `apache` probably created another connection and the module is instantiated again.. and I have now two equal connections running:

```
1151 //from connection 1
1152 //from connection 1
1001 //  from connection 2
1153 //from connection 1
1002 //  from connection 2
1003 //  from connection 2
1154 //from connection 1
...
```

Is there anyway I prevent apache reloading the same module?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most Apache MPM / common configurations will create multiple child processes. You can configure them to use a single process with many threads instead, or use shared memory for your counter.

The simplest way to use shared memory in a portable way is to depend on the "slotmem" and "slotmem_shm" modules.  mod_proxy_balancer uses this. An alternate way is to how server/scoreboard.c uses shared memory directly.